# Drawing confidence bands around multiple lines on the same graph

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have run Moran's I analysis which looks for spatial relationships among features. The analysis was done using the correlog function in the ncf R package and used the first 3 principal components generated from genetic data. the results of that analysis are shown below.

```
distance=c(2.806063,8.208133,14.03604,19.03151,24.44091, 2.806063, 8.208133,14.03604,19.03151,24.44091,2.806063,8.208133,14.03604,19.03151,24.44091 )    

correlation=c(-0.006933,0.029481,-0.071406,0.038319,-0.049990,0.006267,0.055945,-0.048551,-0.035062,-0.031578,0.022629,-0.065584,0.000986,-0.052754,0.0424931)
component=c(PC1,PC1,PC1,PC1,PC1,PC2,PC2,PC2,PC2,PC2,PC3,PC3,PC3,PC3,PC3)

data1<-data.frame(distance,correlation,component)
```

I then used ggplot to plot the results

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data1,aes(x=data1$distance,y=data1$correlation,group=component,colour=component))+theme_classic()+ geom_line(size=1)+geom_point(size=1.5)
```

What I would now like to do is compute the 95% confidence intervals for each of the principal components, and draw that on the ggplots, using a faint shading for the confidence area around each line and keeping the different line colours representing the different PCs. Unfortunately, I am completely stuck and don't know how to go about doing this. Any help will be higly appreciated.

Comment: It helps if you include a reproducible example (we can't create `component` since we can't see `PC1`, `PC2`, etc.)

Comment: You don't need to create component. that variable is included simply as a way of grouping the correlation coefficients represented by the second variable.

Comment: So for your example, why not have, e.g., `component <- factor(rep(1:3, each=5))`? You're less likely to get an answer if your code doesn't run.

Comment: I assume you mean `component=c("PC1","PC1",...,"PC3")`, *not* `component=c(PC1,PC1,...,PC3)`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code doesn't run as is, which is why no one has bothered to respond for the last 10 hours.

**Assuming** you mean:

```
component=c("PC1","PC1","PC1","PC1","PC1","PC2","PC2","PC2","PC2","PC2","PC3","PC3","PC3","PC3","PC3")
```

and that you want the 95% CL for the correlation vs. distance, this will provide it:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data1,aes(x=distance,y=correlation,color=component))+
  geom_line(size=1)+
  geom_point(size=1.5)+
  stat_smooth(aes(fill=component), alpha=.2,
              method=lm, formula=y~1, se=TRUE, level=0.95)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

The main addition is the `stat_smooth(...)` line, which smooths the correlation vs. distance data using a linear model having only the constant term (so, the mean). Note that the default `level=0.95` and the default `se=TRUE` so those clauses are not really necessary in this case.

Also, the expressions in the call to `aes(...)` should reference columns of the data1 (so `x=distance`, **not** `x=data1$distance`), and you do not need the `group=...` clause if `color=...` uses the same grouping variable.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. Thanks also for the other useful comments on the code. I am new to R and just starting to learn how to code.